# return value type does not match the function type (return type is a nested class)

Tags: c++, class, scope, binary-search-tree, definition

I'm practicing programming by implementing a set data structure in C++. I'm currently getting this compiler error related to a function's return type being different from what's indicated in its declaration. The program compiles if I comment out `Set::findSmallest` which is defined at the bottom of set.cpp.

I tried many variations of referring to Node as Set::Node or just Node in the hpp and cpp files, but I can't seem to get it to work.

I can solve this problem by not nesting the Node class inside of the Set class, but I want to practice using nested classes.

```
set.cpp:86:12: error: out-of-line definition of 'findSmallest' does not match any
      declaration in 'Set'
Node* Set::findSmallest(Node* node){
           ^~~~~~~~~~~~
./set.hpp:12:24: note: type of 1st parameter of member declaration does not match
      definition ('Node *' vs 'Set::Node *')
    Node* findSmallest(Node* node);
                       ^
set.cpp:90:20: error: cannot initialize return object of type 'Node *' with an lvalue of
      type 'Set::Node *'
            return nextNode;
                   ^~~~~~~~
2 errors generated.
```

set.hpp

```
#pragma once

class Node;

class Set{
public:
    Set();
    Set(int x);
    void find(int x);
    void insert(int x);
    Node* findSmallest(Node* node);
private:
    class Node {
    public:
        int value;
        Node *smallerNode;
        Node *greaterNode;
        Node();
        Node(int x);
    };
    Node* rootNode;
    Node* nextNode;
};
```

set.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "set.hpp"

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

Set::Node::Node():value(0){
    smallerNode = nullptr;
    greaterNode = nullptr;
}
Set::Node::Node(int x):value(x){
    smallerNode = nullptr;
    greaterNode = nullptr;
}

Set::Set(){
    rootNode = nullptr;
    nextNode = nullptr;
}
Set::Set(int x){
    rootNode->value = x;
    nextNode = nullptr;
}

void Set::find(int x){
    nextNode = rootNode;
    while(1){
        if(x == nextNode->value){
            cout << x << " found!" << endl;
            return;
        }
        else if(x > nextNode->value){
            if(nextNode->greaterNode){
                nextNode = nextNode->greaterNode;
            }
            else {
                cout << x << " not found!" << endl;
                return;
            }
        }
        else {
            if(nextNode->smallerNode){
                nextNode = nextNode->smallerNode;
            }
            else {
                cout << x << " not found!" << endl;
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}
void Set::insert(int x){
    if(!rootNode){
        rootNode = new Node(x);
        return;
    }
    nextNode = rootNode;
    while(1){
        if(x == nextNode->value){
            cout << x << " already exists!" << endl;
            return;
        }
        else if(x > nextNode->value){
            if(nextNode->greaterNode){
                nextNode = nextNode->greaterNode;
            }
            else { 
                nextNode->greaterNode = new Node(x);
                cout << "inserted " << x << endl;
                return;
            }
        }
        else {
            if(nextNode->smallerNode){
                nextNode = nextNode->smallerNode;
            }
            else {
                nextNode->smallerNode = new Node(x);
                cout << "inserted " << x << endl;
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}

Node* Set::findSmallest(Node* node){
    Node* nextNode = node;
    while(1){
        if(!nextNode->smallerNode){
            return nextNode;
        }
        else {
            nextNode = nextNode->smallerNode;
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: You need to move the forward declaration of `Node` into the same scope - into the `class Set`

Answer (score 2):

The error here:

`Node* Set::findSmallest(Node* node){`

is because `Node` is not yet in scope by the time it is used as the return type. You should write

`Set::Node* Set::findSmallest(Node* node){`

instead. Or, using a modern feature,

`auto Set::findSmallest(Node* node) -> Node* {`

Comment: Unfortunately those both give me errors about mismatching return type


```./set.hpp:11:24: note: type of 1st parameter of member declaration does not match
      definition ('Node *' vs 'Set::Node *')```

Comment: Your answer is correct assuming Node is declared before findSmallest in set.hpp. Thanks for your explanation.

Answer (score 1):

There are two syntactic issues there:

1. forward declaring class Node as you do at the beginning is not going to refer as the type Set::Node. Class name Node inside Set class is not the same as Node outside it.
2. you may declare class Node before findSmallest declaration
3. you need to specify Set::Node* as return type

> ```
> //class Node; <- remove this
>
> class Set{
> public:
>
>     class Node {
>     public:
>         int value;
>         Node *smallerNode;
>         Node *greaterNode;
>         Node();
>         Node(int x);
>     };
>
>     Set();
>     Set(int x);
>     void find(int x);
>     void insert(int x);
>     Node* findSmallest(Node* node);
>
> private:
>
>     Node* rootNode;
>     Node* nextNode;
> };
> ```

in cpp file:

```
Set::Node* Set::findSmallest(Node* node){
    ...
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this explanation. As a beginner this was a real head scratcher, but it makes sense now.

Answer (score 1):

To add to @numzero's answer, your declaration of `findSmallestNode` precedes the definition of `Node`, which will give you an error.

You need to either define the function after the definition of `Node`, or forward declare `Node` within `Set`. Note that the declaration of `Node` outside the class *does not* forward declare the `Node` within the class.

Comment: Thank you. The forward declaration of Node outside of the class was causing problems. I forward declared it inside of Set and then I made the return type of findSmallest of type Set::Node*. This is very confusing because the compiler doesn't care if the parameter of findSmallest is Set::Node* or just Node*.

Answer (score 1):

This forward declaration

```
class Node;
```

is redundant and is not the same as the declaration of member class Node within the definition of the class Set.

```
class Node;

class Set{
public:
    Set();
    Set(int x);
    void find(int x);
    void insert(int x);
    Node* findSmallest(Node* node);
private:
    class Node {
    //...
```

So in fact you declared two classes Node. One in the global name space and other as a member of the class Set.

Within the class Set definition the name Node refers to the class member Node in these declarations

```
Node *smallerNode;
Node *greaterNode;
```

However outside the class definition for example in this declaration

```
Node* Set::findSmallest(Node* node){
//..
```

the name Node before the declarator `findSmallest(Node* node)` refers to the name declared in the global namespace. On the other hand the name Node used within the declarator as a parameter type refers to the name Node declared in the class Set scope.

Just remove the forward declaration

```
class Node;
```

It is not used.

You need to define the class Node before referring it. So reformat the class definition the following way

```
class Set{
private:
    class Node {
    public:
        int value;
        Node *smallerNode;
        Node *greaterNode;
        Node();
        Node(int x);
    };
    Node* rootNode;
    Node* nextNode;

public:
    typedef class Node Node;

    Set();
    Set(int x);
    void find(int x);
    void insert(int x);
    static Node* findSmallest(Node* node);
};
```

Pay attention to that as the function findSmallest accepts as an argument a pointer to node then it should be declared as a static member function. In this case it can be defined the following way

```
Set::Node* Set::findSmallest( Node *node )
{
    if ( node != nullptr )
    {
        while ( node->smallerNode ) node = node->smallerNode;
    }

    return node;
}
```

Otherwise within the class definition it should be declared like

```
Node* findSmallest() const;
```

and defined outside the class like

```
Set::Node* Set::findSmallest() const
{
    Node *node = rootNode;

    if ( node != nullptr )
    {
        while ( node->smallerNode ) node = node->smallerNode;
    }

    return node;
}
```

Also pay attention to that this constructor

```
Set::Set(int x){
    rootNode->value = x;
    nextNode = nullptr;
}
```

has undefined behavior because the pointers rootNode was not initialized.

And the data member

```
Node* nextNode;
```

is redundant and shall be removed. It is used as a local auxiliary variable in some member functions. So such a variable should be defined within these functions.

The function find shall not output any message. It is the caller of the function decides whether to output a message. The function shall have the return bool and be declared as a constant member function.

For example

```
bool find(int x) const;
```

The definition of the function outside the class can look the folllowing way

```
bool Set::find( int x ) const
{
    Node *node = rootNode;

    while ( node != nullptr && node->value != x )
    {
        if ( x < node->value ) node = node->smallerNode;
        else node = node->greaterNode;
    }

    return node != nullptr;
}
```

Comment: I really appreciate the response, but unfortunately when I remove the forward declaration, the compiler complains that Node used in the declaration of findSmallest is an unknown type. I also still get an error about an incorrect return type with that change to findSmallest in set.cpp

Comment: @phasor555 As I wrote iin my answer n the function definition you have to write the return type like Set::Node. That is Set::Node* Set::findSmallest(Node* node){ Also place a forward declaration of Node in the class definition. See my updated post.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation.

Comment: It is crystal clear. You even optimized the code. My C++ skills leveled up today.